# how can i attach the framework in WIX

Tags: vb.net, deployment, frameworks, wix, windows-installer

i want to attach .net framework 2.0 file in wix.how can i?so whenever client want to install the msi then it will install the framework directly.so how can i bind the framework in msi package?

reply me soon

Thanking You
Samir

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in a WIX documentation topic: [How To: Install the .NET Framework Using a Bootstrapper](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm)